# How to scroll to a y coordinate using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, coordinates, offset

How to scroll to a y coordinate using jquery without additional plugins given that you know the offset? Additionally, how do you add animation to it?

Comment: you should have a look at jQuerys `.scrollTop()`

Answer (score 2):

With [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/):

```
$(element).scrollTop(offset);
```

([an example](http://jsfiddle.net/t9FGG/2/))

This is the same as changing the `element.scrollTop` property directly. You can also animate the process:

```
$(element).animate({
  scrollTop: offset
}, offset / 3);
```

Comment: you should put it in `document.ready();` at your fiddle, otherwise nothing happens!

Comment: @supersize jsFiddle does that for you.

Comment: not on Firefox 21, interesting! I'm wondering why, on chrome everythings fine!

Comment: Confirmed. It's not working in Firefox for me either. I'm guessing it's a jsFiddle-related issue.

Comment: Oh, apparently Firefox doesn't recognize `scrollTop` on body, but on [`html`](http://jsfiddle.net/t9FGG/2/)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by *@One Trick Pony* you could do that by:

```
$(element).scrollTop(offset);
```

See its documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: Why intentionally post the same answer again?

Comment: @woz I added the documentation!

Answer (score 1):

It's as easy as window.scrollTo(0,yourYvalue);
[W3Schools Windows scrollTo](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp)